# Get the branch name pointed at by HEAD in a remote repository without cloning the remote

Tags: git, version-control

I am currently looking for a workaround to retrieve branch-name pointed by HEAD of remote repository. I don't want to clone the repository.

I directly need some git command to retrieve HEAD branch name. I tried
below command but it only gives SHA commit hash HEAD, but I want branch name instead.

```
git ls-remote ssh://git.dev.pages/opt/git/repos/dev.git <branch>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you do not want to clone the repository?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to clone the repository. I need some direct git command to pull information from remote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use `git ls-remote --symref`

You don't need to clone the remote repo to (programmatically) identify the current branch in that remote repo. [`ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html) has a handy option called `--symref`:

> In addition to the object pointed by it, show the underlying ref pointed by it when showing a symbolic ref. Currently, upload-pack only shows the symref HEAD, so it will be the only one shown by ls-remote.

With this knowledge, you could simply run

```
git ls-remote --symref <remote_repo_url> HEAD
```

and extract the name of the current branch using some `sed`-foo; because `ls-remote` is categorised as a "plumbing" Git command, you can safely use it in scripts.

## Example

```
$ git ls-remote --symref https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags HEAD | \
    head -1 | \
    awk '{print $2}'
refs/heads/master
```

Comment: We do not need to create a local repo.

Comment: @ShaunLutin True!

Comment: Thanks @Jubobs for the answer, actually I am using eclipse jgit library to perform these actions. It would also be great if you can help me to figure out how to use **--symref** option using jgit.

This is currently what I am able to write-
`Collection<Ref> tags = Git.lsRemoteRepository().setRemote(<url>).call();`

- how can I set **--symref** option in above command and get the desired result.

This is the jgit documentation- [link] (http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.6.0.201612231935-r/apidocs/index.html)

Comment: @Himesh I'm not familiar with JGit. In the future, though, include as much (relevant) information in your question as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`--symref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html#git-ls-remote---symref) option. The output shows that `HEAD` points at `master`.

```
> git ls-remote --symref https://github.com/git/git-scm.com.git HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master  HEAD
df55dcad82c2aa8dd7760aadf92b132af1deb8ec        HEAD
```

The concise syntax is `git ls-remote --symref <repository> <refs>`.

Comment: This requires cloning the repository first which I don't want.

Comment: @Himesh Aha. Thank you. I updated both my answer and your question.